# Populate dynamic forms with default data from api in Angular2

Tags: forms, angular, typescript, dynamic, api-design

I have been working with angular2 for a few weeks now and am trying to create dynamic forms for a system settings page. 
The goal: have the api return any number of forms, build the forms inside tabs, forms can have any *type* of field, and populate those forms with default or previously saved data to then modify and save.

What works: Creating any number of forms with any number of input fields.
I need help with populating form with data. 
Here is the items that are generated from the api call. the data that needs to populate these felids i need a separate api call. 
keep in mind each form can have multiple of each of these inputs

```
<li [formGroup]="form" class="form-control-item">
<div [ngSwitch]="item.controlType">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'text'">
        <label class="text-lable " [for]="item.key">{{item.label}}</label>
        <div [ngSwitch]="item.controlType">
            <input [formControlName]="item.key" [id]="item.key" [type]="item.type" class="validate form-control input-lg" input name="{{ name }}" ng-model="name">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
        <label class="label-checkbox" [for]="item.key">{{item.label}}
            <input [formControlName]="item.key" name="{{ item.key }}" ng-model="name" type="checkbox" class="validate form-control checkbox-with-label" >
        </label>
    </div>
    <!--Needs testing with appropriate data-->
    <!--<div *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'">-->
        <!--<label [for]="item.key">{{item.label}}</label>-->
        <!--<input [formControlName]="item.key" [id]="item.key" [type]="item.type" class="validate form-control input-lg">-->
        <!--<select [id]="item.key" [formControlName]="item.key">-->
            <!--<option *ngFor="let opt of item.options" [value]="opt.key">{{opt.value}}</option>-->
        <!--</select>-->
    <!--</div>-->
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'radio'">
        <label [for]="item.key">{{item.label}}</label>
        <input [formControlName]="item.key" [id]="item.key" [type]="item.type" class="validate form-control radio" name="{{ item.key }}" ng-model="name">
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'password'">
        <label [for]="item.key">{{item.label}}</label>
        <input [formControlName]="item.key" [id]="item.key" [type]="item.type" class="validate form-control input-lg" name="{{ item.key }}" ng-model="name">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="errorMessage" *ngIf="!isValid">{{item.label}} is required</div>
```

Here is the component that calls the above:

```
@Component({
selector: 'dynamic-form',
templateUrl: 'dynamic-form.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./dynamic-form.component.scss']
})

export class DynamicFormComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() items: DynamicFormItemBase<any>[] = [];
    form: FormGroup;
    payLoad = '';

constructor(){
}

ngOnChanges(){
    this.form = this.toFormGroup(this.items);
}
ngOnInit(){
    this.form = this.toFormGroup(this.items);
}

onSubmit() {
    this.payLoad = JSON.stringify(this.form.value);
}

private toFormGroup(items: DynamicFormItemBase<any>[] ) {
    let group: any = {};
    items.forEach(item => {
        if(item.value.items){
            // console.log('has an internal item');
        }
        group[item.key] = new FormControl(item.value || '', item.required ? Validators.required : null);
        // console.log(item.value, 'has an internal item');
    });
    return new FormGroup(group);
}
}
```

so again to clarify I make an api call to get how many forms there will be and their names. Then an api call to get the layout of each form by name (from the first api call). all forms build OK. i then have a third api call that returns the config data for that that form; I need to bind this data to each specific form.

I cannot create the typical ng-model="name" name="ng-model" #name way of data binding. or at least I don't know how to implement it dynamically.

```
 <tab class="{{module.name}}-tab" *ngFor="let module of Modules; let i = 

index" heading="{{module.displayName}}" (select)="beforeChange(module.name)">
 <div class="dynamic-form" > 
<dynamic-form [items]="items" >Loading...</dynamic-form> 
</div>
```

Where items is the return from the api. its structured like so: 
First call is like this

```
ModuleList  [{"name":"moduleName","displayName":"Module Name","enabled":true}]
```

some other unrelated code runs and then makes an api call with a parameter of the maduleName to return the layout

```
Array[
    0:Array[
        0:DynamicFormItemBase[
        controlType:"text"
        key:"inputID"
        label:"Input Id"
        order:1
        required:true
        value:ConfigItem [
            displayName:"Input ID"
            items:undefined
            name:"inputID"
            required:true
            type:"text"]
        ]
    ]
```

The thirst API call (after the form is built) will call a different api method with the same parameter of moduleName, and return an object like this

```
Object
    inputID:""
    inputID:1
    inputID:""
    inputID:"default text"
    enabled":true
```

Where each inputID is actually the label ID from the second api call, and the enabled:true should target the Module (current stored in the session storage) from the first api call (if the data is different I will need to update the stored item).

Where the api: items gets passed into the dynamic-form component

```
<tab class="{{module.name}}-tab" *ngFor="let module of dpsModules; let i = index"
                  heading="{{module.displayName}}" (select)="beforeChange(module.name)">
                <div class="dynamic-form"  >
                    <dynamic-form [items]="items"  >Loading...</dynamic-form>
                </div>
            </tab>
```

Comment: What is coming in with the `item.value` in your `toFormGroup` function? That should be the form control value. No so? Can you somehow merge/include the configuration values in with the second API call? Do you at least have a key that you can use to match the configuration values up the form controls?

Comment: each items int he html is one config item array.

Comment: It would be best if you add that sort of thing to the question, and not in the comments, too hard to read. Plus, there is just more room to work with up there. Can you use the `item.key`, which you use as an index in your group array, to lookup a the value from what ever you get from the 3rd API call? What you are trying to do isn't hard, as long as you can link the form group array together with the config values.

Comment: put into question, sorry

Comment: Part of the issue is these forms need to be dynamic for a lot of use cases, I cant add in other values during construction to populate default data. I need a way of  binding the data to the already build form. 
Im not sure i understand _how_ to link the arrays

Comment: More questions I need to have answered in order to help you out. What all is in the `configItem` you mention? I see key, and name, anything else? Like a value? You have in noted in square brackets, so it an array within an array, or an object in an array? In other words, what are you getting back in your 3rd API call? A collection of... what?

Comment: sure Ill add the data structor above ad the end of my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is what I am gathering from your question is correct, the data you get from the *third* API should have the values that you want to apply to the form group that you constructed from the information you got in your *second* API call.

If this is correct, then you need to iterate through the results from the third API call and apply the values to the form group (that should be built by the time you start this).

I am assuming looping/iterating in JavaScript/Typescript is something that you are familiar with.

I am also going to assume that the data from the third API call has a field, or value, that will allow you to identify the form control that it's value needs to be assigned to. For this demonstration, I am going to use `item.key` as the linking token.

Here is the pseudo code for what you need to attempt:

```
for each item.key 
  this.form.controls[item.key].value = item.value;
```

`this.form` is something you already have in your component. You use the `controls` collection in it, along with an indexing value (`item.key` in this case), to read or assign the `value` of the control.

If you do not have something that can provide the link between the form group and the data in the third API call, binding them could prove difficult, if not impossible. If you have something more than just a key, like a key and description, you can use that with some simple concatenation.

I hope this helps you out!

Comment: Im a bit lost, the 'form' has an error of doesnt exist in this component. 
That component being the one that is making the api calls.
code for where the form gets passed the object is above

Comment: Sounds like you need to inject the service you are using to make the API calls into the component you have above and make the call to get the data you need from there. Tell me you know what that means, because telling you how to do that would be well outside of the scope of this question. I am assuming you have picked up some of this in the short time you have been working with Angular.

Comment: I know _some_ about DI, i was hoping for a way to do this outside of the dynamic-form component. As that component is only meant to build form inputs. while the component systemSettings says "hey i need some forms, but they also have default values" this forms are also used on say a create user page, where no default values would be given or even asked for. 
I'll admit I feel little out of my depth here but Im more than willing and eager to learn!

Int he template for systemSettings is where i call the tag <dynamic-form>

Comment: or.. could i not expand the @input perams on <dynamic-form> to include a defaultValue="" option. and make those two api calls happen at the same time? so as each foreach iteration resolves, Im passing in an object of form items, and an object of values. The dynamic-form calls the tag <dynamic-form-item> and passes in each individual item and there i could also expand to include the matching default value. which wold always be empty but overridden by the passed in defaultValue . 
Opinion?

Comment: My opinion is that I like the direction you are headed. It is exactly how I have done this in the past. At some point in your application you will have to bring your form and data together. How you do it is really up to you. I like to utilize services for the API work, inject those into component(s) that stitch it all together for display, and the inevitable "going to the other way" where you send all the information back for storage. I would share what I have done in the past, but the code isn't mine to share. Good resource: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html

Comment: Thanks, I will keep at it with this approach. and mark this particular question as _answered_ albeit not completely solved.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. If I come across any examples I can share, I will add them here.

Comment: I was able to solve this by adding only me model a default prop, so default is undefined until the final api call, but is bound to the items object and updates once the response is in.  I am about to post another question if you want to take a crack at it.